# Object refrence not set to an instance of an object in array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, jagged-arrays

i am very new to C# programming so my question may sound very silly

actualy i am creating an multidimensional string array like

```
public class master
    {
       public List<string> user_selected = new List<string>();
       public List<string> available = new List<string>();
       public List<string> bookedseats = new List<string>();

       public  string [] [] trackbooked=new string[30][] ;

    }
```

now i am assigning some values to it like

```
a[l].trackbooked[i][j] = pb.Name;
```

a is a list of object
`List<master> a = new List<master>();
            a.Add(obj0);
            a.Add(obj1);
            a.Add(obj2);
            a.Add(obj3);
            a.Add(obj4);`

can some one plz help.thank u in adv.

Comment: what is `pb` ? include your tack trace.

Comment: @quantdev  it is inside a foreach loop so pb refers to the picture box

Comment: What is 'a'?  An array of class master?  Is it initialized properly?

Comment: You have a jagged array (an "array of arrays") not a multi-dimensional array. You are never instantiating the inner arrays in your snippet.

Comment: It's likely that either a[l] or pb is null

Comment: @RickS  a[l] is the object of the class i am changing the value of l

Comment: This really isn't a duplicate of that question, the crux of this question is a misunderstanding of jagged array syntax and initialization.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, did you bother to read the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/2589202)? Jagged arrays are right in there.  _Any_ time you see a null reference error, mark it as a dupe of that, no question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only initialized one dimension of your multidimensional array.  See msdn for all the ways you can [initialize a multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

```
 public  string [,] trackbooked=new string[30,30] ;
```

Answer (score -4):

pb.Name.Tostring();
I would venture to guess that whatever pb is that its NAME value isn't returned as a string. You should be able to use the above command to correct your issue.

Comment: ...that wouldn't cause a `NullReferenceException`..